# A really weired issue in (c++) code

Tags: c++

I have defined a variable in my code:

```
double R0;
```

When I set the variable less than 0.9, the code doesn’t run without no error! I have also written `cout<<2;` exactly after `main(){` but the program doesn’t even show that! I am very confused :( what is the problem? When I change R0 to 0.9 or bigger than it, the code runs. This is the most minimal example I could provide:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
vector<double> getBoxCoords(int boxID, double L, double R0, int nbox)
    {
    vector<double> coords(4);
    int yID = ceil((double)(boxID+1)/nbox);
    int xID = fmod((boxID+1-(yID-1)*nbox), nbox);
    if(xID==0)
        xID = nbox;
    coords[0] = (xID-1) * R0; // minX
    coords[1] = (yID-1) * R0; // minY
    coords[2] = min(xID * R0, L); // maxX
    coords[3] = min(yID * R0, L); // maxY
    return coords;
    }


double PBC(double pos, double L)
    {
    if(fabs(pos) > L / 2.0)
        return L-fabs(pos);
    else
        return fabs(pos);
    }

int main()
{
std::cout << 2;
    int N=100;  
    double rho=4.0, v0=0.03, eta=0.2, R0=0.03;
    double L = pow(N/rho,0.5);
    int nbox = (int)ceil(L/R0);
    vector<vector<int>> box_neighbors;
    vector<int> indices;
    for(int i = 0; i < nbox * nbox; i++)  //NUMBER OF BOX
    {
        vector<double> ci = getBoxCoords(i, L, R0, nbox);
        indices.clear();
        for(int j = 0; j < nbox * nbox; j++)
        {
            vector<double> cj = getBoxCoords(j, L, R0, nbox);
            bool xflag=false,
                yflag=false;
            if (PBC(ci[0]-cj[0],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[0]-cj[2],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[2]-cj[0],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[2]-cj[2],L)<R0)
                xflag=true;
            if (PBC(ci[1]-cj[1],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[1]-cj[3],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[3]-cj[1],L)<R0 || PBC(ci[3]-cj[3],L)<R0)
                yflag=true;

            if(xflag && yflag)
                indices.push_back(j);
        }
        box_neighbors.push_back(indices);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

How can I remove the problem? Could anyone provide a runnable answer?

Comment: I highly recommend a debugger

Comment: Do you know what is the problem?@Psi please help me. I'm thinking about it more than ten hours.

Comment: I don't know. You should learn  how to use a debugger

Comment: I debug my code here: https://www.onlinegdb.com/ but there is no output @Psi

Comment: Set up an IDE with integrated debugger and start using breakpoints. I wouldn't rely on an online-debugger like this One

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, the debug `std::cout << 2;` is now shown because you do not end the stream, proper way of doing it is

`std::cout << 2 << std::endl;`

then you will be able to see the debugging message.

Secondly, Your program runs, but takes too much time to finish, when `R0` is small. For the given value, that is, `0.03`, both layers of the loop will execute `nbox * nbox` times which is `27889`, thus, `777796321` in total.

Comment: But std::cout << 2; runs when I put R0 equal to 0.9

Comment: @Sonia - With R0 == 0.9 the inner loop runs 1296 times instead of 777 **million** times. So the 2 appears a lot faster.

Comment: @SoniaSohi As holmeshe said: you did not flush the stream. So your output will get printed on disposal, __at the end of your program__ (which takes time when R0 < 0.9)